# Java server-client callback method

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm new at java but I 've experience on as3. When I was using as3 , I was using some callbacks to notify both server and client when I send either of them a message from the other. But it was a pre-build server named player.io. (as I recall, server was built with c#). There were listeners for messages on both client and server.

But as I started practicing sockets on java, all the examples I saw implement BufferedReader and readLine methods to recieve data from server or client. Problem is , this method waits until it receives data. And this waiting is ofcourse is a big problem, especially for the client.

Is there any way to use callbacks or other methods for communicating between server & client which doesn't cause either of programs to wait?

Comment: You have some research to do!  Even with callbacks, a thread somewhere is waiting for there to be data to read.  I would research Threading and Concurrency in Java and see if you can implement a callback yourself.

Comment: You can use asynchronous socket connection. Here is some details http://www.javaworld.com/article/2853780/java-app-dev/socket-programming-for-scalable-systems.html

Comment: NIO.2 is what I need as I understand, with using threads. Thanks alot guys.